# onKeyDown with Dropzone Js?

Tags: dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I'm trying to make a form ADA compliant which requires tabbing over several dropzone fields that need to use the onKeyDown event handler in addition to being clickable.

I tried adding onkeydown to the dropzoneJsConfig like so:

```
this.dropzoneJsConfig = {
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        clickable: true,
        onkeydown: true,
        ..., }
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I added the tabIndex to a the div encompassing the Dropzone element:

```
return (
        <div tabIndex={0} className={className}
            ref={(div) => this.afterRender(div)}
            data-help-text={help_text}
            data-valid={this.state.valid}
            data-processing={this.state.processing}
            >
            <Dropzone config={this.dropzoneConfig} eventHandlers={this.dropzoneEventHandlers} djsConfig={this.dropzoneJsConfig}>
            </Dropzone>
        </div>
    );
```

Please help!